# JSON Schema oneOf validation

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to create a JSON Schema that will allow a property to be either a number or an object of a specific format.

My data looks like this:

```
{
  "num": 200
}
```

and my Schema  looks like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "num": {
      "type": [
        "number",
        "object"
      ],
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "number"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Variable"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "num"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "Variable": {
      "title": "Variable",
      "properties": {
        "$variable$": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "example": true
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "defaultValue": {
          "type": [
            "string",
            "object",
            "number"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "$variable$",
        "name"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it via a validator here: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

I get this error:

```
Message: JSON is valid against more than one schema from 'oneOf'. Valid schema indexes: 0, 1.
Schema path: #/properties/num/oneOf
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious about how `oneOf` works, but I can't figure out what it might me. Would appreciate any help here, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your case you don't need oneOf at all, you can simply use 
"type": ["number",{"$ref":"#/definitions/Variable"}] instead of "type": ["number","object"]

```
{
  "properties": {
    "num": {
      "type": [
        "number",{"$ref":"#/definitions/Variable"}
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "num"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "Variable": {
      "title": "Variable",
      "properties": {
        "$variable$": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "example": true
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "defaultValue": {
          "type": [
            "string",
            "object",
            "number"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "$variable$",
        "name"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using a schema in `type` hasn't been allowed since draft-03. But, you're also using the array form of `required` which was added draft-04. Whether you are using a draft-03 or draft-04 validator, there is no way this works unless you are using a validator that supports both draft-03 and draft-04 styles. Either way, this solution is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is telling you that both of you `oneOf` schemas are validating as true. It might be surprising that the value `4` is valid against the following schema.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "string": }
  },
  "required": ["foo"]
}
```

It turns out that the `properties` keyword and the `required` keyword don't apply when the value is not an object. So, the above schema is effectively the empty schema (`{}`) when validating against a number (or anything that is not an object). Because the empty schema means there are no constraints, everything is valid.

To fix your problem just add `"type": "object"` to your `/definitions/Variable` schema.

Comment: Nice, this work as well, thanks! Do I understand correctly from your comment on the answer above, that this solution would work for both draft-03 & draft-04 validators, while the one above only works for draft-04 validator?

Comment: You must be using at least draft-4 because in draft-3, required must be on a property and be a boolean.